# Tried all known ways but still not working. Getting make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop

Tags: 20.04, virtualbox, make

I am trying to install `systemc-2.3.3`, but facing some or the other problem at every step. Now I managed to reach till `make`  then `sudo make install`.

But at `make` I am facing problems which says as the title of this question. I would like to mention all that I have tried:

1. I tried to run `make clean` and then `make`.
2. I tried to install all the dependencies (I'm new, so I don't know what role they play), which are:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libqt4-dev
   sudo apt-get install libjack0
   sudo apt-get install libjack-dev
   sudo apt-get install libasound2-dev
   sudo apt-get install libsndfile1-dev
   ```
3. I also tried to run `autoreconf`.

I can see `Makefile`, `Makefile.am` and `Makefile.in` in the `~/Downloads/systemc-2.3.3` directory.

I have the following specifications:

```
Kernel: 5.4.0-47
Ubuntu :20.04.1
```

Please help.

Comment: Where and how (tar? git?) did you obtain the source code? the most recent I can find is 2.3. What is `objdir`? Please post the relevant lines of the error message verbatim.

Comment: Thank you for looking in this. I referred this site :http://rkrara.blogspot.com/2012/12/install-systemc-230-on-linux.html  .

Comment: OK so are you running `make` from `objdir` or from the parent `systemc-2.3.3` directory?

Comment: Yes, im running "make" in "objdir"

Comment: Are you sure about that? you said in the question that you can *"see Makefile, Makefile.am and Makefile.in in the ~/Downloads/systemc-2.3.3/objdir"*. If you followed the linked instructions, then `Makefile.am` and `Makefile.in` should be in the parent directory, while the generated `Makefile` should be in `objdir`.

Comment: radhe@radhe-VirtualBox:~/Downloads/systemc-2.3.3/objdir$ ../configure --prefix=/usr/local/systemc233
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
.....
configure: error: source directory already configured; run "make distclean" there first
radhe@radhe-VirtualBox:~/Downloads/systemc-2.3.3/objdir$ make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

Comment: My bad, its in this :     /Downloads/systemc-2.3.3$.....

Comment: Please [edit] this information into your question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113574/discussion-between-swetha-chilveri-and-steeldriver).